# Получение программой данных от другой программы из конвеера

Tags: c

Как в Си получить данные от другой программы из конвеера? Например команда `du | grep 'mp3'` : `du` передает список файлов в `grep`. Как программно в Си получить этот список?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Например команда du | grep 'mp3' : du передает список файлов в grep.

В данном случае `du` просто пишет в стандартный поток вывода `stdout`, который подаётся на стандартный поток ввода (`stdin`) `grep`'а, который просто читает его квазипострочно и выводит совпадения.

Т.е. для использование своей программы в конвеере не нужно делать ни каких особых ухищрений: просто читать из стандартного ввода любыми обычными функциями, как то `scanf ()`, `getc ()`, `fgets (stdin, ...)`, `read (0, ...)` итд.

Comment: Кажеться надо проверять поток функцией `istty()` и если ответ положительный, читать.

Comment: @NewView, если подразумевалось `isatty ()`, то это не особо относится к вопросу...

Comment: да, да :) `a` съела гуглоклава. Без нее на мой взгляд проблематично отловить использование конвеера.

Comment: @NewView, вопрос, как я понял базовый, не «как отловить», а «как в принципе использовать конвеер»...

Comment: Согласен, базовый. Надеюсь если автор будет пробовать, то учтет и обнаружение конвеера.